# Pandas groupby for excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a spreadsheet that looks like the following (approx 1800 rows) it is generated from a python script extracting information from an Access database:

```
ID  Chemical            Association  Term 
1   1,1-Dichloroethene  exactMatch   1,1-Dichloroethylene
1   1,1-Dichloroethene  exactMatch   Vinylidene Chloride
2   1,2 Epoxyethane     exactMatch   Ethylene oxide  
2   1,2 Epoxyethane     exactMatch   Ethylene oxide (1,2 Epoxyethane)
```

I am wanting to use probably pandas to change the layout of this spreadsheet. I am wanting to create a table like this:

```
ID  Chemical            Association  Term                   (new column)
1   1,1-Dichloroethene  exactMatch   1,1-Dichloroethylene   Vinylidene Chloride   
2   1,2 Epoxyethane     exactMatch   Ethylene oxide (1...   Ethylene oxide
```

I have written the following so far using pandas but am unsure on what to do next:

```
data = pd.read_excel('Chemicals_exactMatch.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
grp = df.groupby(['ID','Chemical','Association'])
```

I assume the following statements will need to be incorporated in this but I am not sure how:

```
df.apply(lambda grouped: grouped['Term'].str.cat(sep="|"))
df.str.split(pat="|")
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to write the following that works:

```
data = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
        .groupby(['ID','Chemical','Association'])
        .apply(lambda grouped: grouped['Term'].str.cat(sep="!"))
        .str.split(pat="!", expand=True)
        .sort_values('Chemical')
        .to_excel('Chemicals_exactMatch.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(['ID',
              'Chemical',
              'Association',
              df.groupby(['ID','Chemical','Association']).cumcount()])['Term']\
  .unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID            Chemical Association                     0                                 1
0   1  1,1-Dichloroethene  exactMatch  1,1-Dichloroethylene               Vinylidene Chloride
1   2     1,2 Epoxyethane  exactMatch        Ethylene oxide  Ethylene oxide (1,2 Epoxyethane)
```

Comment: what print statement do I use to generate this output and also how do i then save this as a new/updated spreadsheet?

Comment: You can add `.to_excel('filename.xlsx')` at the end to output that dataframe to an excel file.